# Adding fisheye plug-in fails to animate() on mouseleave

Tags: jquery

Here is a weird one.

I have an auto-hiding toolbar, which worked perfectly, until I added plug-in called FishEye (aka Interface elements). I did not even use it, I just added it.

With that plug-in loaded, my toolbar fails to animate on mouseleave.

http://jsfiddle.net/wYmvk/
(once you remove eval() with that plug-in - things are back to normal)

I really need this plug-in and don't wanna loose my toolbar. =)

Please help resolving. Thanks.

Comment: You're jsfiddle doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Well, then you are having some serious issues with your browser. Just tried from offshore computer - opens up just fine. =)

Comment: It has just come back out of the void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    $('.toolbar').hover(
    function() {
        var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == -70) {
            $(this).animate({top: '0'}, 300);
        }
    },
    function() {
        var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == 0) {
            $(this).animate({top: '-70'}, 300);
        }
    }
```